# Can not locate resource in root of executable jar

Tags: java, maven, classpath, embedded-resource, shiro

I have a program that is configured to use an Apache Shiro ini file for storing its users and permissions.

The following code works in the IDE

**Code**

```
public static String loginModule(String heelName, String heelPass) {

        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();

        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        Subject usr = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(heelName, heelPass);


        try {
            usr.login(token);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            return ae.toString();
        }
```

but when compiled with maven javafx plugin, the program is unable to find the shiro.ini file in its classpath.  The following error is produced:

**Error**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.apache.shiro.config.Configur
ationException: java.io.IOException: Resource [classpath:shiro.ini] could not be
 found.
        at org.apache.shiro.config.Ini.loadFromPath(Ini.java:242)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.Ini.fromResourcePath(Ini.java:225)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.<init>(IniSecurityM
anagerFactory.java:69)
        at Login.loginModule(Login.java:23)
        at LoginController.attemptToLoginbutton(LoginController.java:178)
        at LoginController$1.handle(LoginController.java:98)
        at LoginController$1.handle(LoginController.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Bu
ttonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h
andleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEve
nt$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Quantum
Toolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Glas
sViewEventHandler.java:387)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.ja
va:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resource [classpath:shiro.ini] could not be foun
d.
        at org.apache.shiro.io.ResourceUtils.getInputStreamForPath(ResourceUtils
.java:139)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.Ini.loadFromPath(Ini.java:240)
        ... 61 more
```

Since this is a maven project, the ini is located in the /src/main/resources folder when looking at the project source code.

I have verified that the shiro.ini file is in fact present in the root directory of the executable jar. Any suggestions on how to overcome this error??

**Potential resources**

https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/config/IniSecurityManagerFactory.html

http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try:

```java
new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:/shiro.ini");
```

instead of:

```java
new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
```

Comment: thank you for your suggenstion! However this causes the same afformentioned error to occour in both the compiled version and in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is more forgiving than the compiled program. It still is able to find "Shiro.ini" when given "shiro.ini" however the compiled program requires that this capitalization error be corrected.

```
new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
```

corrected to:

```
new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:Shiro.ini");
```

rectifies the issue